# Tryng to find a Pokemon-like cartoon where there the main character had a red monster and they captured monsters on talismans

Tags: story-identification, tv, cartoon

So, there was this protagonist with a red monster, they captured monsters in a talisman and were able to travel through a mirror. I remember one chapter where a friend of the protagonist fell in love with a yellow monster that was a sort of jellyfish woman, anyone knows about it? This was like 7 years ago on Disney XD

Answer (score 9):

Possibly [Yo-kai Watch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Yo-kai_Watch_(2014_TV_series)_episodes)? It ran on Disney XD from 2015 to 2020. The main character, Nate, partners with the cat Yo-kai Jibanyan in the first episode, who is a red monster:

[image]